# chicken shish kabobs the night before cooking

Tags: chicken, raw

I want to prepare Hawaiian chicken shish kebobs the night before cooking.  Do I need to be concerned about the raw chicken touching the veggies overnight in the fridge?

Answer (score 2):

Having the vegetables and meat marinate or assembled together is fine, so long as the finished item is thoroughly cooked.

When grilling skewers, you cook long enough to have the meat to a safe temperature, so the vegetables should be cooked through by then.

For greatest safety, make sure there is a little spacing between the items on your skewer, and if this is not done make sure they are cooked through.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to worry about it as long as you clean your veggies. I did it all the time. Just don't leave it in your fridge for too long.

If you go to groceries stores, you often find many types of bbq skewers. And they leave it there for couple days so I guess everything is fine :)